# Grandma likes coffee but not tea

Tags: pattern, word-property

*Note: My grandma is a little odd. She only likes certain things. Solve this puzzle by providing phrases that are true. For example: Grandma likes A but not B*

- Grandma likes coffee but not tea.
- Grandma likes fall but not autumn.
- Grandma likes seconds but not minutes.
- Grandma likes dark but not light.
- Grandma likes one but not two.
- Grandma likes false but not true.

---

(Puzzle Credit: My friend Derek)

Comment: I believe that this is a Grandma Likes Word™ puzzle in sheep’s clothing.

Comment: Good call.Worth it to rework the question?

Comment: It's up to you.  If it were my choice, I'd slap on a word-property tag and leave the rest alone.

Comment: @Beastly Why did you make that edit?

Comment: @grgarside oh that was just a test. Probably should have done it somewhere else..

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Grandma likes

> Flowers but not plants
>  Fingers but not toes
>  Fridges but not magnets
>  In but not out
>  Pancakes but not sweets
>  Paper clips but not staples

Why?

> Because grandma does not like **T**ea!

Comment: This is an oldie but a goodie.