# Stocks and shares: Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, knowledge, language

In his retirement Grandpa likes to manage his own investments. He studies global company stocks, their earnings, products, dividends all kinds of statistics and numbers and makes his buy choices

> Grandpa likes Boeing Corporation but not Lockheed Martin
>
> Grandpa likes Roku but not Netflix
>
> Grandpa likes Unilever but not Proctor and Gamble

I wonder why

Comment: Isn't this a "Grandma likes" type riddle? See [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45059/grandma-likes-coffee-but-not-tea)

Comment: @KradCigol Flagged for what? It's a different riddle, just similar style of clues.

Comment: I was wrong - this is different. Deleted previous comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grandpa likes:

> Companies whose stock symbol is a number in another language

Specifically,

> Grandpa likes BA (8, Chinese), ROKU (6, Japanese), and UN (1, French), and dislikes LMT, NFLX, and PG.

Comment: There is a Language Tag for the puzzle

Comment: I've edited my answer - hopefully this is a little closer.

Answer (score 5):

Grandpa dislikes:

> Company names with three consecutive consonants: Lo**ckh**eed, Ne**tfl**ix, Ga**mbl**e

Because:

> Gra**ndp**a has started subconsciously doubting *his own* abilities to spend money wisely, and is projecting it onto those companies. You might need to start monitoring his spending habits.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe Grandpa likes

> Companies with numbers in their name

Explicitly

> Bo**ein**g Corporation - German for one 
>  **Roku** - Japanese for six 
>  **Un**ilever - French for one

Comment: If using such far fetched argumentation, I could also say the Netflix rot13(pbagnvaf vk, Ebzna sbe avar).

Comment: That is a good point

Comment: You are on thee right track @hexomino.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Grandpa likes:

> Companies with rivers in their name

Because:

> Boeing Cor**pora**tion
>  R**oku**
>  U**nile**ver
>
>  Pora, Oku and Nile are all river names

Comment: Wow. Did not know that @pirate. My answer is different. Thanks

Comment: sorry to spoil the party: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Ock

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to [this riddle:](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45059/grandma-likes-coffee-but-not-tea)

Grandpa

> Does not like T.

Comment: Boeing Corporation?

Comment: Good point! Let me see. Thanks, @JonMarkPerry!

Answer (score 0):

Grandpa dislikes:

> Companies with less than 40% vowels in their name.